# how to identify stationarity of a series by interpreting acf and pacf graphics

Tags: stationarity, acf-pacf

I've been told that these following acf graphics basically shows that both series are stationary, but i didn't really understand why. 
Is it if both autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation can gradually decay to 0 then the series is stationary? Or it's a lot more complicate than this..?
[image]
[image]